# using AJAX with php to display the data on the web page after some calculation is finished

Tags: php, ajax

Here's the situation. I have a php file. I can get the value in one of the variables array in this php file really fast. But further processing on the data inside the array takes too long resulting into timeout. I would like to use AJAX so that when the page is loaded, the processed result is displayed and updated as soon as individual data inside the variable array is processed.

Any example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a fine idea. What's the problem?

Comment: How do i do it? Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note to OP: this site is not a fast-food chain where you can shout behind the desk and you get what you want under minutes.

Comment: Did i ordered you a food or what? @fabrik

Comment: @kailashbuki "How do i do it" sounds like that, yep.

Comment: @fabrik No offense ... but i have already mentioned my appreciation to anyone who helps me with an example and that applies to those too who put forward their word of advice ... so pathetic that instead of suggesting, you are playing war of words with me

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this might be to turn off [buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), have a look at the PHP [flush](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) method, the comments explain a neat method you could try

You can then do your processing at the bottom of your page (after flushing the output) after the closing `</html>` tag and update your results with javascript when the processing has completed

Comment: This is a pattern called "Comet". Useful, but can cause trouble : lot of connexion to be maintened open on the server, can't use gzip or deflate on apache, can't use output buffering on PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow (I would call this a "standard way" of doing what you need):

1. request that generates page stores to DB data that should be processed
2. cron job runs in background and
   periodically checks if mentioned DB
   has any data to process; if yes, it
   starts processing data; after
   processing it stores results to DB
3. ajax script that's located in
   page periodically (say, once in 15
   seconds; depends on how long it
   takes to process the data) connects
   to server to check if data is
   already processed; if it is, it
   loads results, if no, it may load
   some status information - like
   number of jobs in queue or something
   like "15% done"

You might also think about using some flash client and java server to communicate over plain TCP socket connection to get the data faster and with smaller overhead.